# How to display report execution time in client's local time zone in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have reports in SSRS2008R2 which uses this code to return the report execution time in the local time zone of the client running the report:

```
=System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow,TimeZoneInfo.Utc.Id,First(Fields!TenantTimeZoneName.Value, "Company"))
```

In order for this to run in SSRS2008R2, I added the reference assembly below:

```
System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

These reports have run fine for years until now. I am building up a new SSRS2012 server and when I attempt to deploy a report to the new server, I get the following error during deployment:

```
The definition of the report '/MyReport' is invalid.
```

Assuming that this just meant that I would have to switch the reference assembly to point to a higher release System.Core, I changed the assembly to point to System.Core 4.0 instead of System.Core 3.5.  When I do that, I get this error:

```
Error while loading code module: ‘System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked the file location and the System.Core assembly shows up just where the path indicates it is supposed to be.  I also checked the GAC and the assembly is there.

I really need to get this working ASAP but I am at an impasse.  Any ideas?

Comment: [Here is a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260761/how-do-i-resolve-report-deployment-error-when-referencing-system-core-4-0-unde) where someone solved a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but for anyone looking. It is best to remove the reference to System.Core and call the same function via system.

The example below converts a datetime from "UTC" to "EST".

```
=System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(Fields!YOURDATETIMEHERE.Value, "Dateline Standard Time", "Eastern Standard Time")
```